# C++, считывание из файла

Tags: c++

Надо считать значения в вектор из файла(кол-во значений в файле не известно)

```
 for(int i=0;!input.eof();i++){

      input>> a[i];

  }
```

Я хочу, что бы увеличение параметра `i` происходило пока не достигнут конец файла. Но видимо я что-то организовал не правильно. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так:

```
for (int i = 0; input; i++) {
    input >> a[i];
}
```

А если количество значений неизвестно, то правильнее было бы:

```
for (int i = 0; input; i++) {
    int tmp;
    input >> tmp;
    a.push_back(tmp);
}
```

Если нужно сохранить значение `i` после цикла, то так:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; input; i++) {
    int tmp;
    input >> tmp;
    a.push_back(tmp);
}
```

Не забывайте, что таким образом последнее число считается два раза. Первый вариант:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; input; i++) {
    int tmp;
    input >> tmp;
    if (input)
        a.push_back(tmp);
    else
        i--;
}
```

Второй вариант:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; input; i++) {
    int tmp;
    input >> tmp;
    a.push_back(tmp);
}
i--;
a.pop_back();
```

Comment: Второй цикл не выполняется, i=0;

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.

Comment: @FlagShtok исправил ответ

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

...
std::vector<int> a;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(input), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(a));
```

Comment: @dzhioev что порекомендуете для изучения итераторов?

Comment: Страуструпа можно почитать, например. Вообще итераторы - очень простая концепция. И большенство алгоритмов стандартной библиотеки работают только с итераторами.

Comment: @dzhioev спасибо